# Android JOBB don't dump good

Tags: android

I tried create an OBB file and then, dump this file to see all works fine. 
I have a folder called "HOLA" in C:\Users\abreu20011\Desktop\HOLA with the next distribution:

```
HOLA
\_>hola.txt (i wrote "hello world" inside)
\_>emulator-arm.exe
\_>emulator-mips.exe
\_>emulator-x86.exe
```

I put emulators file, because when I trying to compress with the text file only, I received the next error when I write the sentence:

```
jobb -pn es.test.test -pv 1 -d C:\Users\abreu20011\Desktop\HOLA -o hola.obb

Slop:0 Directory Overhead: 0
Slop:289 Directory Overhead: 224
java.io.IOException: no data clusters
        at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.<init>(Fat.java:129)
        at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.create(Fat.java:96)
        at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.Fat.SuperFloppyFormatter.format(SuperFloppyFormatter.java:236)
        at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:414)
```

So, I fattened the directory with this emulators, and the jobb tool worked fine:

```
Slop:0 Directory Overhead: 0
Slop:2453 Directory Overhead: 608
```

But the real problems arise when I try to dump the obb file. Since the jobb tool creates the obb file in the same directory of the tool, I wrote the dump sentence:

jobb -dump hola.obb -d C:\Users\abreu20011\Desktop

The program extracts a partial file of emulator-arm.exe and wrote the next error:

```
Package Name: es.test.test
Package Version: 1
LFN = emulator-arm.exe / SFN = ShortName [/☺[←►▬←☺ifl -- 2f 1 5b 1b 10 16 1b 1 6 9 66 6c ]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2335
        at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.ClusterChain.readData(ClusterChain.java:225)
        at de.waldheinz.fs.fat.FatFile.read(FatFile.java:126)
        at com.android.jobb.Main.dumpDirectory(Main.java:137)
        at com.android.jobb.Main.main(Main.java:315)
```

Why I can't create an obb file of his size is smaller?
and why I can't dump the original file?

Thanks for your help and for your time! :)